# query of subquery SQL

Tags: sql

I'm pretty new to SQL language but I can't find a solution to this topic. Let's suppose I have the table "Table" like this

[sample table called Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FOouw.png)

I need to select all rows of an item el_A where at least one row has el_B = 5

so in the above case the result should be :

[Query result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V2jLF.png)

I was thinking about this solution but it doesn't work :

```
SELECT * FROM Table WHERE Table.el_A = 
(
SELECT * FROM Table WHERE el_B = 5
).el_A
```

Could you help me? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can use `exists`:

```
select t.*
from table t
where exists (select 1
              from table t2
              where t2.el_a = t.el_a and t2.el_b = 5
             );
```